# Travel destinations API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

When you [google a country's name](https://www.google.com.br/destination?q=canada&site=search&output=search&dest_mid=/m/09c7w0&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYoPSDkcLaAhUDj5AKHf9BD6AQ6tEBCG8oBDAF), the results page displays a section called "travel guide", which includes travel info about that country and a little list of destinations as shown in the image below.

[image: google travel]

Is there a way to fetch this kind of data (eg, country name, description, things to do (as an array with title, description, image), popular trips, when to visit, etc...) via the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults)?

I've been researching it for a while now and haven't been able to get anywhere near.

If it isn't possible, is there another api that could get me somewhere near to this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple Hotel search APIs but in your case you need tour/attractions data.

Try this Google Places API URL. You will get the point of interest/Attraction/Tourists places in (For Eg:) New York City. You have to use the CITY NAME with the keyword Point Of Interest

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=new+york+city+point+of+interest&language=en&key=API_KEY
```

This API call results are same as the results of the below google search results.

[New York point of interest](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&btnG=Search&q=New%20York%20point%20of%20interest)

2)
If you want some third party data then you can also try [Musement API](https://www.musement.com/business/us/api)

[Experinces/Places in New York](https://www.musement.com/us/search?q=new%20york)

Comment: Nice! Just for future reference: to get images from the maps api response, use the [Place Photo web service.](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos)