# Scraping Google Destinations

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm preparing a tour around the world and am curious to find out what the top sights are around the world, so I´m trying to scrape the top destinations within a certain place. I want to end up with the top places in a country, and their best sights. Google Destinations was recently added as a a great functionality for this.

For example, when googling `Cuba Destinations`, Google shows a card with destinations Havana, Varadero, Trinidad, Santiago de Cuba.

Then, when googling `Havana Cuba Destinations`, it shows `Old Havana, Malecon, Castillo de los Tres Reyes Magos del Morro, El Capitolio.

Finally I´ll turn it into a table, that looks like:

```
Cuba, Havana, Old Havana.
Cuba, Havana, Malecon.
Cuba, Havana, Castillo de los Tres Reyes Magos del Morro.
Cuba, Havana, El Capitolio.
Cuba, Varadero, Hicacos Peninsula.
```

and so on.

I have tried the API call as shown in [Travel destinations API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887062/travel-destinations-api), butthat does not provide the right feedback, and often yields OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

The code below returns an error:

```
URL = "https://www.google.nl/destination/compare?q=cuba+destinations&site=search&output=search&dest_mid=/m/0d04z6&sa=X&ved=0API_KEY"

import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

#URL = "http://www.values.com/inspirational-quotes"
r = requests.get(URL) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 
print(soup.prettify())
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use something like Selenium for this as the page makes multiple XHRs you will not be able to get the rendered page using requests alone. First install Selenium.

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

Then get a driver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
(Depending upon your OS you may need to specify the location of your driver)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = ("https://www.google.nl/destination/compare?q=cuba+destinations&site=search&output=search&dest_mid=/m/0d04z6&sa=X&ved=0API_KEY")
browser.get(url)
time.sleep (2)
html_source = browser.page_source
browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "lxml")
# Get the headings
hs = [tag.text for tag in soup.find_all('h2')]
# get the text containg divs
divs = [tag.text for tag in soup.find_all('div', {'class': False})]
# Delete surplus divs
del divs[:22]
del divs[-1:]

print(list(zip(hs,divs)))
```

Outputs:

```
[('Havana', "Cuban capital known for Old Havana's colonial architecture, live salsa music & nearby beaches."), ('Varadero', 'Major Cuban resort town on Hicacos Peninsula, with a 20km beach, a golf course & several parks.'), ('Trinidad', 'Cuban town known for Plaza Mayor, colonial architecture & plantations of Valle de los Ingenios.'), ('Santiago de Cuba', 'Cuban city known for Afro-Cuban festivals & music, plus Spanish colonial & revolutionary history.'), ('Viñales', 'Cuban town known for Viñales Valley, Casa de Caridad Botanical Gardens & nearby tobacco farms.'), ('Cienfuegos', 'Cuban coastal city, known for Tomás Terry Theater, Arco de Triunfo & Playa Rancho Luna resorts.'), ('Santa Clara', 'Cuban city home to the Che Guevara Mausoleum, Parque Vidal & ornate Teatro La Caridad.'), ('Cayo Coco', 'Cuban island known for its white-sand beaches & resorts, plus reef snorkeling & flamingos.'), ('Cayo Santa María', 'Cuban island known for Gaviotas Beach, Cayo Santa María Wildlife Refuge & Pueblo La Estrella.'), ('Cayo Largo del Sur', 'Cuban island, known for beaches like Playa Blanca & Playa Sirena, plus a sea turtle center & diving.'), ('Plaza de la Revolución', 'Che Guevara and monuments'), ('Camagüey', 'Ballet, churches, history, and beaches'), ('Holguín', 'Cuban city known for Parque Calixto García, the Hacha de Holguín axe head & Guardalavaca beaches.'), ('Cayo Guillermo', 'Cuban island with beaches like Playa del Medio & Playa Pilar, plus vast expanses of coral reef.'), ('Matanzas', 'Caves, theater, beaches, history, and rivers'), ('Baracoa', 'Beaches, rivers, and nature'), ('Centro Habana', '\xa0'), ('Playa Girón', 'Beaches, snorkeling, and museums'), ('Topes de Collantes', 'Scenic nature reserve park for hiking'), ('Guardalavaca', 'Cuban resort known for Esmeralda Beach, the Cayo Naranjo Aquarium & the Chorro de Maíta Museum.'), ('Bay of Pigs', 'Snorkeling, scuba diving, and beaches'), ('Isla de la Juventud', 'Scuba diving and beaches'), ('Zapata Swamp', 'Parks, crocodiles, birdwatching, and swamps'), ('Pinar del Río', 'History'), ('Remedios', 'Churches, beaches, and museums'), ('Bayamo', 'Wax museums, monuments, history, and music'), ('Sierra Maestra', 'Peaks with a storied political history'), ('Las Terrazas', 'Zip-lining, nature reserves, and hiking'), ('Sancti Spíritus', 'History and museums'), ('Playa Ancon', 'Beaches, snorkeling, and scuba diving'), ('Jibacoa', 'Beaches, snorkeling, and jellyfish'), ('Jardines de la Reina', 'Scuba diving, fly-fishing, and gardens'), ('Cayo Jutías', 'Beach and snorkeling'), ('Guamá, Cuba', 'Crocodiles, beaches, snorkeling, and lakes'), ('Morón', 'Crocodiles, lagoons, and beaches'), ('Las Tunas', 'Beaches, nightlife, and history'), ('Soroa', 'Waterfalls, gardens, nature, and ecotourism'), ('Guanabo', 'Beach'), ('María la Gorda', 'Scuba diving, beaches, and snorkeling'), ('Alejandro de Humboldt National Park', 'Park, protected area, and hiking'), ('Ciego de Ávila', 'Zoos and beaches'), ('Bacunayagua', '\xa0'), ('Guantánamo', 'Beaches, history, and nature'), ('Cárdenas', 'Beaches, museums, monuments, and history'), ('Canarreos Archipelago', 'Sailing and coral reefs'), ('Caibarién', 'Beaches'), ('El Nicho', 'Waterfalls, parks, and nature'), ('San Luis Valley', 'Cranes, national wildlife refuge, and elk')]
```

**UPDATED IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
for place in ["Cuba", "Belgum", "France"]:
    url = ("https://www.google.nl/destination/compare?site=destination&output=search")
    browser.get(url) # you may not need to do this every time if you clear the search box
    time.sleep(2)
    element = browser.find_element_by_name('q') # get the query box
    time.sleep(2)
    element.send_keys(place) # populate the search box
    time.sleep (2)
    search_box=browser.find_element_by_class_name('sbsb_c') # get the first element in the list
    search_box.click() # click it
    time.sleep (2)
    destinations=browser.find_element_by_id('DESTINATIONS') # Click the destinations link
    destinations.click()
    time.sleep (2)
    html_source = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "lxml")
    # Get the headings
    hs = [tag.text for tag in soup.find_all('h2')]
    # get the text containg divs
    divs = [tag.text for tag in soup.find_all('div', {'class': False})]
    # Delete surplus divs
    del divs[:22]
    del divs[-1:]
    print(list(zip(hs,divs)))

browser.quit()
```

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! Thank you so much. I'm confident I can tweak your code to suit my exact needs, I'm really happy with that.

A problem I do have is with the URL: if I replace Cuba with France, the results still come back with Cuba... Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: Updated to give a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Google Places API URL. You will get the point of Interest/Attraction/Tourists places in (for example) New York City. You have to use the CITY NAME with the keyword Point Of Interest.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=new+york+city+point+of+interest&language=en&key=API_KEY`

These API results are same as the results of the Google search results below.
https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&btnG=Search&q=New+York+point+of+interest

Two more little tips for you:

- You can use the Python Client for Google Maps Services: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python
- For the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` problem, make sure that you add a billing method to your Google Cloud project (with your credit card or free trail credit balance). Don't worry too much because Google will give you some thousand free queries each month.